# Is it possible to create Salesforce Change sets ready to be deployed in Prod programatically?

Tags: salesforcedx, c#

I can go to my Salesforce sandbox and create  a change set with all dependencies and then go to Production and import. But can i do all of this programatically with C# ?
So create the change set with all dependencies , package it up and from the program deploy to Prod, by making sure all tests pass and reach 75% ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should not rely on Change Sets for orchestration of development pipelines or practices. Change Sets are an old technology with substantial limitations (including minimal API access); no, you can't create them via API.

Instead, consider practicing the [Org Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/org-development-model), using a version control system as source of truth and deploying from that VCS, or pursue the [Package Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model) and use Unlocked Packages as your vehicle for deploying metadata artifacts between orgs.

In either case, the source of truth and center of pipeline automation should be source control. You can orchestrate deployments using the Metadata API in most languages, although building scripting around Salesforce CLI will be the easiest and fastest route. The Metadata API can deploy Salesforce customizations to any org, regardless of sandbox/prod status.